# Groovy converting between Map and Closure

Tags: groovy

So I know i can convert a Closure (`cdata`) to a Map (`toObj`) as follows:

```
Closure cdata = {
    a = 1
    b = 2   
    c = 3
}
Map toObj = [:]
cdata.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
cdata.delegate = toObj
cdata()
println(toObj)
```

Which prints out `[a:1, b:2, c:3]`

But my question is how do I properly convert a Map to a Closure? This seems to 'work' but it isn't taking the same approach

```
Map mdata = ["a":1, "b":2, "c":3]
Closure toClos = {}
mdata.every { toClos[it.key] = it.value }
```

Is there a more correct method of object conversion here?

Comment: Why would you want to convert a map to a closure?

Comment: is curiosity a good enough reason

Comment: Sure, but I can't think of a simple way to do it... Nor a reason why it would be a useful thing to do  I was hoping you had one 

Comment: Curiosity pulled me in to posting an answer 

Answer (score 2):

Ok...how's this?

```
// Given a map, return a closure that sets properties on the delegate
def makeClosure(Map m) {
    { ->
        m.each { k, v ->
            delegate."$k" = v
        }
    }
}

// Generate a closure from our map of keys
Map mdata = [ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 ]
def clos = makeClosure(mdata)

// Some imagined class for testing
@groovy.transform.ToString
class SomeClass {
    Integer a = 0
    Integer b = 0
    Integer c = 0
}

def d = new SomeClass()

// Set the delegate to our imagined class
clos.delegate = d
clos.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST

// And call the closure
clos()

// Prints SomeClass(1, 2, 3)
println d
```

However, all this can be avoided by simply doing:

```
Map mdata = [ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 ]

def d = new SomeClass(mdata)

println d
```

Answer (score 1):

strange question...

```
Map m = [a:1,b:2,c:3]
Closure mapper = { src, dst ->
        src.each{ k,v -> dst[k] = v }
        return dst
    }.curry(m)


//test
def obj2 = mapper( [x:0] )
println(obj2)
assert [x:0,a:1,b:2,c:3]==obj2
```