# Using Groovy map for DSL arguments

Tags: jenkins, groovy, closures, dsl

Following the [link here](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2016/04/21/dsl-plugins/) we have our own DSL extension which is defined like this in a file `vars/buildFlow.groovy`:

```
Map<String, Object> mapFromClosure(Closure body) {
    Map<String, Object> config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()

    // other things
}
```

In my `Jenkinsfile`, I can use this as such:

```
buildFlow {
    // different args
}
```

I would like to be able to dynamically populate the args to `buildFlow` but am unsure how to work with Groovy and closures. I have a `Map` of everything I want based on my conditions, but I can't pass the `Map` to `buildFlow` like this. Is there a way to convert the `Map` args to the closure constructor?

```
Map flowArgs = [
    argA: 1,
    argB: 2
]

buildFlow {
    flowArgs
}
```

I've seen solutions which talk about using `ConfigObject` but that is restricted:

```
Scripts not permitted to use new groovy.util.ConfigObject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically populate the arguments for `buildFlow` using a `Map`, you might consider converting the [`Map`](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-maps) to a [closure](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-closures) in Groovy.
That can be done by iterating through the `Map` and applying each key-value pair as properties to a closure.

First, modify the `mapFromClosure` method in `vars/buildFlow.groovy` to handle both `Closure` and `Map` types:

```
Map<String, Object> mapFromClosure(Object body) {
    Map<String, Object> config = [:]

    if (body instanceof Closure) {
        body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        body.delegate = config
        body()
    } else if (body instanceof Map) {
        config.putAll(body)
    }

    // other things
    return config
}
```

Then, create a utility method to convert a `Map` to a `Closure` (as in "[Groovy converting between Map and Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76009108/6309)"):

```
Closure mapToClosure(Map map) {
    return {
        map.each { key, value ->
            delegate."$key" = value
        }
    }
}
```

Use this utility method in your `Jenkinsfile` to convert your `Map` to a closure before passing it to `buildFlow`:

```
Map flowArgs = [
    argA: 1,
    argB: 2
]

buildFlow mapToClosure(flowArgs)
```

Result:

```bash
Jenkinsfile
    |
    └── buildFlow (Accepts Closure or Map)
            |
            └── mapFromClosure (Handles both Closure and Map)
                    |
                    └── mapToClosure (Converts Map to Closure)
```

That would provide the flexibility to handle both closures and maps in your DSL, allowing dynamic argument passing to `buildFlow`.
The `mapToClosure` function is used within the Jenkins pipeline to convert the `Map` of arguments into a `Closure` before passing it to `buildFlow`. That makes sure the pipeline script stays within the boundaries of what is allowed by Jenkins' script security.

Comment: Seems like this works without modifying mapFromClosure using your mapToClosure! That DSL is managed by another team, so may not have levity to extend to allowing a Map input. Thank you so much.

Comment: @TomNash Great, well done!